# '& > *' in React's styles

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, styling

I have following code:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  row: {
    '& > *': {
      fontSize: 12,
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      color: 'rgba(33,34,34,0.5)',
      letterSpacing: 0.5,
      lineHeight: '16px',
    },
  },
}));
```

anybody can explain me what the line does mean:

```
'& > *': {
```

Appreciate.

Comment: "& > *" is the same as "> *" to my knowledge and translates to: Every direct descending element. So, every element thats a direct child of the element that you are applying the styles to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`>` is a [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) in CSS

> The `>` combinator selects nodes that are direct children of the first element.

`*` is a [universal selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors) in CSS.

> Selects all elements. Optionally, it may be restricted to a specific namespace or to all namespaces.

`&` is [a parent selector](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector) in SCSS

> In CSS-in-JS it may refer to *the current component selector*

> The parent selector, `&`, is a special selector invented by Sass that’s used in nested selectors to refer to the outer selector

Since React-Material-UI uses [JSS](https://github.com/cssinjs/jss) in its implementation, such syntax is possible.

So in a combination of all above, `& > *` means: apply the CSS for all element types for all current parent's direct children

Comment: Question, is `&` required. Should not `> *` be sufficient? My take is, `&` usually refers to *and has class*. like `.parentClass { &parent2Class { ... } somethingElse { ... } }`

Comment: `&` being named the parent selector can be ambiguous and confusing because it's not technically selecting the parent but rather the **current component** that is being styled. The Sass documentation itself switches between "parent selector" and "outer selector" which doesn't help at all – but what it means is the outermost selector. In CSS-in-JS solutions the outermost selector doesn't exist because they target the component that you apply the styles to. As a result I think you should clarify that `&` matches the current component.

Comment: In Sass/SCSS `& > *` and `> *` are equivalent. I experimented by comparing `foo { > bar { key: value; } }` and `foo { & > bar { key: value; } }`. The generated CSS is the same between the both of them. You can try this in a Sass playground such as [Sassmeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/). I also tested with [Styled Components](https://styled-components.com/), a CSS-in-JS solution, and there is no observable difference between them.